# Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm sure this is a very common question, but I can't make it work even after following several tutorials about it.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 lts and I just installed Ruby on Rails with Rbenv, but then, after running `rails server` I get the `Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.4` message. 
How can I make it work?

Comment: Either install ruby 2.1.4 and use it. Or update your gemfile to use ruby 2.3.1 (something might not work here, if not all of your code is compatible with 2.3.1)

Comment: Are you using RVM or something like that to support different versions of Ruby on your machine?

Comment: @MarsAtomic - He is using rbenv.

Comment: I tried to install 2.1.4 but it didn't work for some reason, probably cause I'm doing it wrong. I can't update the gemfile, has to be 2.1.4

Answer (score 2):

As Sergio pointed you, you need to update your Ruby or your Gemfile.

In my experience, there are not a lot of major changes between Ruby 2.1 and 2.3, so I suggest updating your Gemfile.

If you don't want to do that, then here is how to install Ruby 2.1.4:

```
rbenv install 2.1.4
```

Also, be sure to set the version:

```
rbenv local 2.1.4

ruby -v
```

Should return 2.1.4

[rbenv reference](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions)

Comment: `# rbenv install 2.1.4
rbenv: /home/ricardo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N) y
Downloading ruby-2.1.4.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.4.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.1.4...

WARNING: ruby-2.1.4 is nearing its end of life.
It only receives critical security updates, no bug fixes.

Installed ruby-2.1.4 to /home/ricardo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4`

Comment: It worked, but now I have loop issue: when I set it to 2.1.4 it says The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions: 2.3.1, but if I set it to 2.3.1 it says Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.4 ...
And I know it worked on this laptop with the same gemfile before

Comment: `gem install bundler; bundle`

Answer (score 0):

```
rvm --default use 2.1.4

rvm use 2.1.4@"folder name" --create
```